# How to resample from month to annual and back to monthly where monthly values = annual?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a monthly time series which I have converted to annual average using

```
ts_ann =ts_mo['Value'].resample('A').mean()
```

What I would like to do next is to create a new time series where the monthly values equal the annual. That way I can graph the monthly and have the annual averages highlighted but also with monthly frequency. Not having much luck searching for a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a left outer merge of both DataFrames on their index. This will produce a DataFrame with `NaN` from January to November in the yearly column and the actual yearly mean at Dezember.
Afterwards you fill the `NaN` values backwards using pandas `fillna` method:

```
ts_mo.merge(ts_ann, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left').fillna(method='bfill')
```

By specifying `suffixes=('_monthly', '_yearly_average')` inside the `merge` call,  you can give the resulting columns meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried and received the following...
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: I think I know why I got the error but I am new to python so not sure of the solution!  

In: type(ts_ann) 
out: pandas.core.series.Series

and

In: type(ts_mo)
out: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: It seems your annual data is a series and not a DataFrame. Maybe you should use: ts_ann =ts_mo[['Value']].resample('A').mean() which creates a sub-DataFrame from ts_mo instead of only using one parantheses around 'Value' that creates a series. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupby and transform to obtain yearly averages. Assign this to a new column and you are ready to plot.

```
ts_mo['Year_mean'] = ts_mo.groupby(ts_mo.index.year)['Value'].transform('mean')
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(400)

ts_mo = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2016',end='2018', freq='M'),
    'Value': np.random.randint(0,100, size=24)
}).set_index('date')

ts_mo['Year_mean'] = ts_mo.groupby(ts_mo.index.year)['Value'].transform('mean')

ts_mo.plot(x=ts_mo.index, y=['Value','Year_mean'])
plt.show()
```

Returns:

[image]